# React Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into a weird problem. I'm new to React and and I only want to retrieve a headline and the thumbnail image from The Guardian API.

When I try to set the src of the image as `data.fields.thumbnail` I get the error `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined`

The weird thing is that I see the image loading properly in the screen just before the error message appears, which makes me think that thumbnail is in fact defined?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function NewsData() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const urlApi = "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?order-by=relevance&use-date=published&q=crypto&api-key=fbd25144-951c-40ac-8dfa-63fdd9a1eb06&show-fields=thumbnail"

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(urlApi)
            .then(response => setData(response.data.response.results['0']))
    }, [urlApi])


    return (
        <div>
            <h4>{data.webTitle}</h4>
            {/* <p>{data.fields.thumbnail}</p> */}
            <img src={data.fields.thumbnail}></img>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewsData
```

Comment: Why are you binding urlApi const which will have no change in the array of your useEffect ?

Comment: good point! Was following several tutorials and must've overlooked it. Either way I don't think this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I don't think too, try to log your response instead of setting your state data

Comment: Yeah I did, and it works when I log it. Once I put the {date.fields.thumbnail} on the return, it gives me the error. I feel like I'm going crazy

Comment: Okay.. actually I do not can how it can work. I checked your api response  from the url you got in your code which as no `thumbnail` elements. 
Any way if it worked nice, you can try to use a condition to render your img

Comment: Initially, `data` is an empty array and on the first render, `data.fields` will be `undefined` (arrays do not have a `fields` property). You need to guard against using the data until you have it (and there are many questions for this exact topic).

Answer (score 1):

First an advice. You have to see what data your API is returning you.

Then you will know how to access your data.

Right now you are accessing it like so `response.data.response.results['0']`, indeed you response has nos object with such path.

If you want for exemple to access the id of your element you can access it like this: `response.results[0].id` .

**Note** that your API is not returning you any src path. In other word 'thumbnail' cannot be defined.

**EDIT:**

Since you told me in a comment you checked the data and it is the correct way nice.

In order to get your data without trouble use a condition.

For exemple :

```
{
    data ? 
    <img src={data.fields.thumbnail}></img> : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use data.fileds.thumbnail before it loads. This is why it is undefined.

You can do a validation, if data exists, then show this section of code.